# Samsung s3 bug with listview

Tags: android, performance

I have worked on a custom list view which is a pull down to refresh listview but it is showing a strange error , whenever i try to run it on my galaxy s3 , it starts saying

> I/Choreographer(698): Skipped 340 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

and the scrolling of the listview is painfully slow. Attached is video of testing on s3 and an htc device and it works flawlessly on HTC. Any pointers that why is this happening?

HTC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o1UXv_-Uco
S3: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjjC07M70Gk

**edit:code added**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener {
private LinkedList<String> mListItems;
TmbResultListViewAdapter adapter;
Button editButton;
public static boolean refreshOnDrag = true;
private boolean isloading = false;
private MyTask task;
PullToRefreshListView lv;
private ProgressBar footer;
private TextView statusBar;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRefreshOnPull(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    statusBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusbar);

    editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    lv = (PullToRefreshListView) getListView();
    lv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            if (refreshOnDrag) {
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });
    lv.setOnScrollListener(this);
    lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    footer = (ProgressBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);

    mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

    // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

    adapter = new TmbResultListViewAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void edit(View v) {
    if (!adapter.showEditControlls) {
        adapter.showEditControlls = true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        editButton.setText("Done");
    } else {
        adapter.showEditControlls = false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        editButton.setText("Edit");
    }
}

public void setRefreshOnPull(boolean val) {
    this.refreshOnDrag = val;
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ;
        }
        adapter.resetItems();
        return mStrings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");

        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).onRefreshComplete();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

private String[] mStrings = { "Abbaye de Belloc",
        "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu",
        "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre", "Allgauer Emmentaler" };

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    int loadedItems = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
    int offSet = (((int) ((firstVisibleItem - 1) / adapter.getItemPerPage())) *  adapter
            .getItemPerPage()) + 1;
    statusBar.setText(offSet + " of "
            + (offSet + adapter.getItemPerPage() - 1));
    if ((loadedItems == totalItemCount) && !isloading) {
        if (task == null || (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
            task = new MyTask();
            task.execute();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).addFooterView(footer);
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        isloading = true;
        adapter.loadMoreData();
        // ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), null,
        // android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        // LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)
        // findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        // linLayout.addView(pb);
        Log.d("*****", "Loading...");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isloading = false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).removeFooterView(footer);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();

}
}
```

**adapter code added**
I have seen that when ever i try to scroll the skipping frames get even worse.
so may be i am doing a lot of work on the getview method

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //View convertView = convertView;
    // TmbJSON eventDetail;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tmb_result_listitem, null);
        mViewHolder = new viewHolder();

        mViewHolder.resultTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.resultTitle);
        mViewHolder.resultPeriod = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.resultPeriod);
        mViewHolder.resultVenue = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.resultVenue);
        mViewHolder.resultDescription = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.resultDescription);
        mViewHolder.resultIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.resultIcon);
        mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkuncheckicon);
        mViewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mViewHolder.headerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemheader);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    try {

        mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon.setVisibility(showEditControlls ? ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.GONE);
        mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon.setImageResource(mCheckedState.get(position) ? R.drawable.starschecked : R.drawable.starsunchecked);
        mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (mCheckedState.get(position)) {
                    mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon
                            .setImageResource(R.drawable.starsunchecked);
                    mCheckedState.set(position, false);
                } else if (!mCheckedState.get(position)) {

                    mViewHolder.checkUnCheckIcon
                            .setImageResource(R.drawable.starschecked);
                    mCheckedState.set(position, true);
                }
                theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), position+"th Event un/checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        String name = masterList.get(position).name;// eventDetail.smartStringWithPath(TmbJSON.arrayListObjectWithStrings("name"));
        String detail = masterList.get(position).detail;// eventDetail.smartStringWithPath(TmbJSON.arrayListObjectWithStrings("detail"));
        String venue = masterList.get(position).venue;// ((JSONObject)eventDetail.object).getJSONArray("prs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("loc").getString("name");
        String period = masterList.get(position).period;// ((JSONObject)eventDetail.object).getJSONArray("prs").getJSONObject(0).getString("ts_z");

        mViewHolder.resultTitle.setText(name);
        mViewHolder.resultPeriod.setText(period);
        mViewHolder.resultVenue.setText(venue);
        mViewHolder.resultDescription.setText(detail);
        if((position) % (itemPerPage) == 0 && position!=0)
        {   mViewHolder.headerTextView.setText((position+1)+" of "+(int)(position+20));
            mViewHolder.headerTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            mViewHolder.headerTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);

        }
        int forthPos = getCount() - itemPerPage + 4;
        int tenthPos = getCount() -  itemPerPage + 10;
        int sixteenthPos = getCount() - itemPerPage + 16;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: For -whatever you believe in-s sake, just read the message. You have to do heavy load in a background thread, i.e. any data fetching goes into an async task. You're just lucky on the HTC device. Samsung does many things wrong, but you're definitively responsible for this behaviour. Also: The scrolling on the HTC device is horribly laggy as well.

Comment: It will be easier if you could show code. Are you doing any background operation (like call webservices, etc) on UI thread? See each vendor customizes android, it might be the issue with Samsung that the threshold for getting the error is less as compared to HTC

Comment: Samsung devices seem to be very sensitive to work on the UI-thread. Are you loading the images / data from a webservice? (and if so, on the UI-thread?)

Comment: code is added , i had tried to do as much work on the background thread as possible but the error is still there

Comment: Then you're most probably firering the execution of data fetching too often. Try adding `refreshOnDrag = false;` to `if (refreshOnDrag) {
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }`. Or for the purpose of debugging: Log the `execute` method and watch if your log is flooded

Comment: i tried with refreshondrag=false but still same result

Comment: @chossen-addict Then what does your log say?

Comment: it is saying the same thing , 
choreographer , skipping 340 frames

Comment: @chossen-addict Did you add a debug output to the `execute` method and run it again?

Comment: @stefan i have added the log to execute but the getdatatask.execute() is only called when the list is pulled down to refresh. so it is not getting called

Comment: @chossen-addict my mistake, was looking in the wrong section of the code. Your problem must be in `onScroll` since scrolling lags terribly from what I can see in your videos. Best to log every execution of task creation or to get a proper (well-tested) implementation from a third party.

Comment: thanks for the help but onscroll is also only getting called when i scroll the list , so i cant see that to be a problem

Comment: thanks for the help every one , got it resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one else , facing the same kinda issue you will have to look some where you are using a lot of memory , in my case it was the image in listview that was causing the issue , i have replaced the image with a lower quality one and its working fine now , But its still beyond me that how does same list view works better on a lower end device then a higher end device. Beyond me .