# Android ImageView Outof memory

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

This is my code, It response Outofmemory error on samsung mobile!
I searched very much in google but not answered.
When Showing Image in list show force close.

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

      private final Activity context;
      private final String[] web;
      private final String[] imageId;

      public CustomList(Activity context,String[] web,String[] img) {
        super(context, R.layout.tag_list_item, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = img;
      }

      @SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        try{
        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("cat_"+imageId[position].trim().toString(), "drawable", 
           context.getPackageName());
         //resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
         imageView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(resourceId));
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString()+"   "+imageId[position].trim().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return rowView;
      }

}
```

Comment: What size is the image you are loading?

Comment: may be you are loading `.bmp` file to image view

Comment: Your code is ok. `OutOfMemory` could happen due to many reasons depending on context. So it's quite hard to answer what happens looking at just tiny piece of code.

Comment: Images is just thunmbnail and format is png,  code is okey in some mobiles but in samsung show force close,  and error is outofmemory

Comment: For debugging purpose, try to display the same png image without the ListView and see what happens. And...catch the Exception and display the  error (try/catch).

Comment: it show outofmemory error

Comment: follow this link i hope it can help you
 **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401568/samsung-s3-bug-with-listview**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the heapsize in manifest and ended.

Answer (score 0):

You should optimize your code to prevent recreate the row every time you scroll.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtTitle =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // this line doesn' t recreate the view but reuse the one created before
    }

   viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

    try{

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("cat_"+imageId[position].trim().toString(), "drawable", 
       context.getPackageName());
     //resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
     viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(resourceId));

    }catch(Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString()+"   "+imageId[position].trim().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return convertView;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public ImageView imageview;
}
```

Hope it help....happy coding :)